# ReactNative: how to center text?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, react-native

How to center Text in ReactNative both in horizontal and vertical?

I have an example application in rnplay.org where **justifyContent="center"** and **alignItems="center"** is not working:
https://rnplay.org/apps/AoxNKQ

The text should being centered.
And why is there a margin at the top between the text (yellow) and parent container?

Code:

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topBox}>
          <Text style={styles.headline}>
            lorem ipsum{'\n'}
            ipsum lorem lorem
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.otherContainer}>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  topBox: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headline: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18,
  marginTop: 0,
    width: 200,
    height: 80,
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  otherContainer: {
    flex: 4,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);

module.exports = SampleApp;
```

Comment: Like this: https://rnplay.org/apps/1hbnSA ?

Comment: this is not horizontal centered

Comment: ok, so this: https://rnplay.org/apps/1hbnSA, updated

Comment: WAAAA... textAlign ? i knew it would something really stupid.... you should post this as an answer

Comment: The title states React Native but the tag says React JS. Please fix this.

Answer (score 524, accepted):

From `headline`' style remove `height`, `justifyContent` and `alignItems`. It will center the text vertically. Add `textAlign: 'center'` and it will center the text horizontally.

```js
  headline: {
    textAlign: 'center', // <-- the magic
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginTop: 0,
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't work with a `width` unless you wrap it in a `<View>` with `justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',`

Comment: your magic not worked however `width: "100%",` worked

Comment: I only got it to work by changing it to  "text-Align: center;"

Comment: 2023: Types of property 'textAlign' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TextAlign

Comment: perfect answer => " textAlign: 'center'

Answer (score 98):

Already answered but I'd like to add a bit more on the topic and different ways to do it depending on your use case.

You can add `adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}` (currently undocumented) to `Text` Component to auto adjust the size inside a parent node.

```js
  <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true} numberOfLines={1}>Hiiiz</Text>
```

You can also add the following in your Text Component:

```js
<Text style={{textAlignVertical: "center",textAlign: "center",}}>Hiiiz</Text>
```

Or you can add the following into the parent of the Text component:

```js
<View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center"}}>
     <Text>Hiiiz</Text>
</View>
```

or both

```js
 <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center"}}>
     <Text style={{textAlignVertical: "center",textAlign: "center",}}>Hiiiz</Text>
</View>
```

or all three

```js
 <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center"}}>
     <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true} 
           numberOfLines={1} 
           style={{textAlignVertical: "center",textAlign: "center",}}>Hiiiz</Text>
</View>
```

It all depends on what you're doing. You can also checkout my full blog post on the topic

https://medium.com/@vygaio/how-to-auto-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-into-a-nodes-width-in-react-native-9f7d1d68305b

Comment: this should be expected : <Text style={{textAlignVertical: "center",textAlign: "center",}}>Hiiiz</Text>

Comment: man you saved my 1.5 hours. I was trying to do same but couldn't until this answer as : `textAlignVertical: "center", textAlign: "center" `, as <Text/> Component Style.

Comment: textAlignVertical is Android only. None of these solutions are aligning my text vertically, only horizontally.

Comment: `justifyContent: "center"` in the parent component was the magic sauce. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Set these styles on the image component:

```js
{
  textAlignVertical: "center",
  textAlign: "center"
}
```

Answer (score 19):

```
textAlignVertical: "center"
```

is the real magic.

Answer (score 14):

**Horizontal** and **Vertical** center alignment

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center'}}>
     <Text> Example Test </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Only solution that worked for me in terms of centering <Text> inside a <View> not just horizontally, but also vertically. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

this is a example for **Horizontal** and **Vertical** alignment simultaneously

```
<View style={{width: 200, flexDirection: 'row',alignItems: 'center'}}>
     <Text style={{width: '100%',textAlign: 'center'}} />
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip that inline styles must be enclosed in {{double-curly-braces}}.

Answer (score 11):

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, textAlign: 'center' }}>A</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 10):

The following property can be used: `{{alignItems: 'center'}}` becaus you are using item `<Text>` not "string".

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
 <Text> Hello i'm centered text</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Even if this may be the solution to the question, please add some more explanation so we all can learn.

Comment: Please, improve it because you are using two asterisks to circulate the main correction but it's not clear and the other part is confuse

Answer (score 8):

You can use `alignSelf` property on Text component

```
{ alignSelf : "center" }
```

Answer (score 5):

Wherever you have `Text` component in your page just you need to set style of the `Text` component.

```
 <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}> Text here </Text>
```

you don't need to add any other styling property, this is spectacular magic it will set you text in center of the your UI.

Answer (score 5):

Simple add

```
textAlign: "center"
```

in your styleSheet, that's it.
Hope this would help.

edit: "center"

Answer (score 4):

Okey , so its a basic problem , dont worry about this
just write the <**View**> component and wrap it around the <**Text**> component

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
<Text> Write your Text Here</Text>
</View>
```

***alignitems:center*** is a prop use to center items on crossaxis

---

***justifycontent:'center'*** is a prop use to center items on mainaxis

Answer (score 3):

Set in Parent view

```
justifyContent:center
```

and in child view alignSelf:center

Comment: Keys should be in camel case `justifyContent` and `alignSelf`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        navigationView: {
        height: 44,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor:'darkgray',
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        alignItems: 'center' 
    },
    titleText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
})


render() {
    return (
        <View style = { styles.navigationView }>
            <Text style = { styles.titleText } > Title name here </Text>
        </View>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the use cases mentioned in the other answers:

To center text in the specific use case of a **BottomTabNavigator**, remember to set showIcon to **false** (even if you don't have icons in the TabNavigator). Otherwise the text will be pushed toward bottom of Tab.

For example:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'white',
    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    showIcon: false, //do this
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 20,
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    tabStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'grey',
      marginTop: 0,
      textAlign: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      textAlignVertical: "center"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

first add in parent view
  flex:1,
  justifyContent: 'center', 
  alignItems: 'center'

then in text add
   textAlign:'center'

Answer (score 1):

used

textalign:center

at the view

Answer (score 1):

If you're running into this issue on Android, like I was, make sure to set `includeFontPadding` to `false` ([documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#includefontpadding-android)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use two approaches for this...

1. To make text align center horizontally, apply this Property `(textAlign:"center")`.
   Now to make the text align vertically, first check direction of flex. If flexDirection is column apply property (`justifyContent:"center"`) and if flexDirection is row is row apply property (`alignItems : "center"`) .
2. To Make text align center apply same property (`textAlign:"center"`). Now to make it align vertically make the hieght of the `<Text> </Text>` equal to view and then apply property
   (`textAlignVertical: "center"`)...

Most Probably it will Work...

Answer (score 0):

In many instances, ReactNative supports CSS style properties, names as **camelCase** instead of the standard CSS **dasherized-lisp-style** (aka **kebab-case**)

Which is the same as React/JSX.

The CSS property `text-align` has the direct equivalent: `textAlign`

So usually, it's worth trying the CSS property, converted to **camelCase**.

Answer (score -1):

```
<View style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>
<Text>React Native</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

headline: {
textAlign: 'center',fontWeight: 'bold'}