# CSS isn't applied as expected in React Native when parent component already has styles defined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I need some help understanding how CSS is applied in React Native. It doesn't seem to work like normal CSS in web.

Basically, I have a `<CardSection>` component that is imported into this `<LoginForm />`

Here's the code for it:

*CardSection.js export:*

```
const CardSection = ({ children }) => {
    const { containerStyle } = styles
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {children}
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = {
    containerStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        position: 'relative'
    }
}
```

I can't override the style that was defined in this parent Component (or maybe that it inherits) inside a child element.

Here is the code that is not acting properly:

*LoginForm.js:*

```
renderError() {
    const { errorContainerStyle, errorTextStyle } = styles
    const { error } = this.props

    if (error) return (
        <CardSection style={errorContainerStyle}>
            <Text style={errorTextStyle}>
                {error}
            </Text>
        </CardSection>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                // code removed
            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>
                // code removed
            </CardSection>

            {this.renderError()}

            <CardSection>
                {this.renderLoginButton()}
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

Here is my current attempt at styling. I'm trying to `center` the error text, but it won't move. It stays to the left no matter what properties I put on `errorContainerStyle`.

```
const styles = {
    errorContainerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        lineHeight: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        alignText: 'center',
        paddingLeft: 10
    },
    errorTextStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: 20,
        lineHeight: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        color: 'red',
    }
}
```

[image]

I read up and found some evidence of passing an array of styles in, but that didnt work when I did it in each/both CardSection locations.

> I'm really confused why it's not just using the styles I pass in at the child-most location. Why is it not even making the background blue?

It's React 16, React Native 0.49, and Android API level 23 (Marshmallow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center text, use

```
textAlign: 'center'
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571418/reactnative-how-to-center-text)

Comment: Damn, I swear I tried that. I see I had it backwards, but I feel like I tried this on both elements with both textAlign and alignText. It's working with just textAlign: 'center'. It was also throwing an error with textAlign but only when it was on the parent. This CSS is ornery. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I just didn't have the right property though. I was starting to think React Native CSS was totally illogical. I Have react-devtools hooked up now too which is letting me edit CSS on the fly real easy.

Answer (score 1):

To align in  center use the following :

```
textAlign: 'center' !important ;
```

or according to your code use the same line of code as given below

```
const styles = {
errorContainerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    lineHeight: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center' !important,
    alignItems: 'center'!important,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignText: 'center'!important,
    paddingLeft: 10
},
errorTextStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 20,
    lineHeight: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center' !important,
    alignItems: 'center' !important,
    color: 'red',
}
}
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks, textAlign on the error text element is what fixed it. Your code is utilizing what looks like some CSS priorities, but I can't run those props as is. My ES Lint was telling me I need typescript. I appreciate the reminder about onLoad priorities though.