# React Native: Perfectly align Text in circle

Tags: react-native, vertical-alignment

I have a circle button (made with `borderRadius`) in React Native. The text in the component should be centered both vertically and horizonatlly.

Horyzontally it's fine, but the vertical alignment seems to fail whatever I do. Even if it looks good on large cicles with small fontSize, the small circles proof it wrong!

```
        <View style = {{
          alignItems:'center', 
          justifyContent:'center',  
          backgroundColor:'yellow', 
          borderColor: this.props.color,    
          width:size,   height:size, 
          borderRadius:size, 
          borderWidth:borderWidth,
        }}>
            <Text style = {{
              textAlign: 'center',  
              backgroundColor:'none', 
              fontSize:fontSize, 
              lineHeight:fontSize,
            }}>
              {this.props.title}
            </Text>
        </View>
```

Although already answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571418/), I'm unable to center text (in this case) in a circle properly.

[image: The + is not centered][image: Green background show it better]

As one can see on the image with the green background of the `<Text>`-Component, the text is just not centered perfectly. Even though the  itself is perfecttly aligned...

Here is a snack for Expo with the whole code reduced to the necessary and with different example sizes: https://repl.it/@PaulHuchner/Centered-Text-in-Circles

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the previous answer with only Text and calculating line-height. which looks like a little overkill and didn't work for me. So here's my answer.

I am using View as the container with justifyContent:center

```
<View style={{
width: 40,
height: 40,

borderRadius: 20,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: 'black',
borderStyle: 'solid',

justifyContent: 'center'}}>
 <Text style={{fontSize: 20,textAlign: 'center'}}>20</Text></View>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to set the same `fontSize` and `lineHeight` as the circle's diameter, which has `borderWidth` of `10` included to it.

Due to the `borderWidth`, the text is being cut and overlayed over the circle. The `lineHeight` assigned to the cut `Text` is more than required, hence it is displayed `misaligned`.

Therefore you need to reduce the `fontSize` and the `lineHeight` based on the borderRadius of the circle, to function properly for all dimensions.

```
<Text style = {{
     textAlign: 'center',
     backgroundColor:'green',
     fontSize:fontSize - 2 * borderWidth, //... One for top and one for bottom alignment
     lineHeight:fontSize - (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 2 * borderWidth : borderWidth), //... One for top and one for bottom alignment
   }}>
```

Here's a snack [link](https://snack.expo.io/r1JiAHXaz)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Actually this doesn't solve it neither :(
I don't care if the text exceeds the circle as long as it is centered. I made a snack with your changes:
https://repl.it/@PaulHuchner/Centered-Text-in-Circles-1

Comment: Your snack doesn't work for me neither :( it looks [like this](http://www.paulyro.com/paul/screenshot.png): now the letters are too high. Is it only my device?

Comment: Are you testing on android because I haven't seen on that just yet. There might be different behaviour on android.

Comment: Yes, and also the simulator the snack shows it like that for android :( Any other ideas? It really seems, that the problem is the alignment of the font in the <Text>-Component

Comment: You are the best! Looks perfect. S

Comment: Well I was too enthusiastic about it :( It is much better, but still not the real center! If you increase the fontsize (e. g. 120) it will be more noticeable. There must be a simple/general solution, right?

Comment: It seems that I'm unable to align the Text in the <Text>-Component itself. So the problem is not depending at all on the circles or the alignment of the <Text>-Component in the circle.Still any ideas about this?

Comment: You should take into account that lineHeight will not work properly with accessibility font scale(for both IOS and Android). I just run into this issue recently. So most likely lineHeight prop most likely should be avoided from usage in RN or at least there should be some additional rules on how to use it

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked the best for me was instead of using a Text Element, instead, use a plus Icon. The difference is that the viewBox of "+" as a character isn't centered.

If that is confusing look at these three letters
A+a

Notice that "A" is taller than "+" and also "a". So instead, use a PLUS icon instead and it will be perfectly centered such as 24x24 px. This drove me mad!