# React Native: How to center the second line text

Tags: react-native

I want to style a line text in the same row as another text. Then I put 2 texts in the same view and make `flexDirection: 'row'`.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 300, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
   <Text style={styles.headerDetail}>{t('Certificate by')}: </Text>
   <Text style={styles.detail}>{selectedFileInfo.certificate}</Text>
</View>
```

But the problem is the second text is long and when it's overflow, it will rearrange at the new line like this.

[image]

I want it to be at the center of this view. Any way I can do this?

Or if I put `textAlign: 'center'` to the second text, it will be like this.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571418/reactnative-how-to-center-text

Comment: It's not my issue

Comment: Maybe FlexWrap can help you with that: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex-wrap

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
textAlign: 'center'
```

If you are using Tailwind you can use:

```
text-center
```