# React Native - Text/Emoji is not vertically aligning in view

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I tried several configurations, but I am unable to vertically center emoji inside a view.

This is the code I am using:

```
<View style={{width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: "red", justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center"}}>
<Text style = {{fontSize: 100, textAlign: "center", backgroundColor: "black"}}>

</Text>
</View>
```

**Output:** (See gap above and below emoji)

[image]

Also, I tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571418/reactnative-how-to-center-text) question. None seems to work out. Is this expected behavior or bug in react native. Thanks

Comment: I copy and pasted your code, and the spaces look fine on my simulator (iOS 14.4, iPhone 12). Can you tell us if this is for iOS or Android, and maybe post some more code? I'm sure you checked already, but you might have some styles in a parent element that's affecting your emoji.

Comment: @JBWilson Actually, this code I tried on "https://reactnative.dev/docs/text", just to confirm my hunch. So code runs on browser in chrome. And I used the exact code, just for testing. So there weren't any parent styles. But I first noticed this issue with android.

Comment: This looks like bug, I reported it for now, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32198