# ReactNative cant center text with height provided to the container

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

When i add height to my container my text goes out of the center position as in the image provided. How can i center it with height of 24 for the container added?
I also taked a look here, where someone has had similar problem - [ReactNative: how to center text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571418/reactnative-how-to-center-text)
but still no luck with the centering.
[text out of center image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5gA8.png)

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>1</Text>
        </View>

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            alignSelf: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            borderRadius: 12,
            minWidth: 24,
            height: 24,
            borderWidth: 3,
            borderColor: "red",
        },
        text: { textAlign: "center", textAlignVertical: "center" },
```

Comment: Don't add height, add vertical padding

Comment: FYI `textAlignVertical` will not work in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please :)

```
container: {
            alignSelf: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            borderRadius: 12,
            minWidth: 24,
            height: 24,
            borderWidth: 3,
            borderColor: "red",
            alignItems:"center // try this
        },
```